# Function Fields and Valuations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Take some homogenous irreducible polynomial $F(X_0,X_1,X_2)$ and set,
$$ X = \{ (a:b:c) \in \mathbb{P}^2_k ~ | ~ F(a,b,c) = 0 \} $$
i.e. $X$ is a projective plane curve.

Denote by $K=k(X)$ to be the function field of $X$.

Since $K$ is a function field of dimension $1$ we can choose a rational function $f\in K$ which is transcendental over $k$ and $K$ is a finite extension, so pick some $g\in K$ such that $K = k(f)(g)$ (this is always possible even if $k$ has positive characteristic).

Fix some surjective valuation $v:K^{\times}\to \mathbb{Z}$ (which is trivial on $k^{\times}$). Suppose $f,g\in \mathscr{O}_v$ i.e. $v(f),v(g)\geq 0$. Then we can view $f,g$ are being defined at $v$, so $f(v),g(v)\in k$.

Construct the point $p = (f(v):g(v):1)\in \mathbb{P}^2$.

How does one show that $p\in X$ and that $\mathscr{O}_p$ is contained in $\mathscr{O}_v$.

(To clarify, $\mathscr{O}_p$ are rational functions defined at $p$, and $\mathscr{O}_v$ are rational functions defined at $v$. The distinction is that $p$ is a point in the projective plane while $v$ is a "point" on the abstract curve of valuations.)

Answer (score 0):

Your "surjective valuation $K^\times \to k$" doesn't make much sense, did you mean $K\to \Bbb{Z}\cup\infty$. What do you mean with $f(v)$, and what is $p$ and $\mathscr{O}_p$.

Note that $K=k(x)[y]/(F(x,y,1))$. Did you mean $f=x,g=y$, in which case $p=(a:b:1)$ is a point of your curve and $\mathscr{O}_p$ makes sense: the localization of $R=k[x,y]/(F(x,y,1))$ at the maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b)$. Note that I meant that $v$ is any non-trivial valuation on $K$ which is trivial on $k$ such that $v(x)\ge 0,v(y)\ge 0$ and $a,b\in k$ are the images of $x,y$ under the homomorphism $\mathscr{O}_v\to \mathscr{O}_v /\mathfrak{m}_v\cong k$.

$v(x)\ge 0,v(y)\ge 0$ gives that $R\subset \mathscr{O}_v$.

$x-a,y-b\in \mathfrak{m}_v$ so $(x-a,y-b)\subset \mathfrak{m}_v\cap R$,
and since $(x-a,y-b)$ is a maximal ideal, it means that $$(x-a,y-b)=\mathfrak{m}_v\cap R$$ which makes it clear that any $h\in R,\not\in (x-a,y-b)$ is not in $\mathfrak{m}_v$ ie. $h^{-1}\in \mathscr{O}_v \implies \mathscr{O}_p\subset \mathscr{O}_v$.

Comment: I am still reading through this, but to answer your question, $\mathscr{O}_p$ are the rational functions which are defined locally at $p$. Whereas, $\mathscr{O}_v$ are the rational functions which are defined locally at $v$ i.e. it is the ring of all functions which are $\geq 0$ with respect to the valuation $v$.

Comment: No your $\mathscr{O}_p$ doesn't make sense, what is the meaning of "defined locally at $p$". What I am saying is that you certainly want $\mathscr{O}_p$ to be the localization of $k[f,g]$ at $(f-a,g-b)$. Iff $p$ is a smooth point of $Spec(k[f,g])$ then it is $=\mathscr{O}_v$.

Comment: Maybe we are using different definitions? For me, $\mathscr{O}_p$ consists of rational functions $\phi\in K$ such that $\phi$ can be written as $\phi = a(x_0,x_1,x_2)/b(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ and $b(p) \not = 0$. Therefore, both $\mathscr{O}_p$ and $\mathscr{O}_v$ are subsets of $K$ and the goal is to show one is the subset of the other.

Comment: This is ok if $p$ is a point of your curve, ie. if $f=x,g=y$. Otherwise you need to say which curve it is a point of, to tell in which ring your $a,b$ are and the homomorphism $b\to b(p)$.